# Graph without four cycle and large chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory

Give an example of graph without four cycle with chromatic number greater than $3$.

Answer (score 2):

This relates to [Steinberg's conjecture](https://math.la.asu.edu/~checkman/Steinberg.html).
It conjectures that a planar graph wiht no $C_4$ and no $C_5$ is 3-colorable.
The added $C_5$ property is there because there are planar graphs with no $C_4$ that are not 3-colorable.  Here's what they give :

[image: A planar graph without no $C_4$ that is not 3-colorable]

There are probably smaller examples if we don't restrict ourselves to planar graphs, but it doesn't seem easy to construct.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that there are graphs with arbitrarily large girth and chromatic number, meaning that we can prevent the graph from containing any copies of $C_n$ for any $n < m$ (for fixed $m$) and make the chromatic number arbitrarily high.

Comment: Ah if you have an idea of this type of construction I'd be interested to see this as an alternate answer.

Comment: Erdös didn't use an explicit construction--he used the probabilistic method.